# How to provide dependency value in visual composer

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to use like this

```
'dependency' => array(
     'element' => 'service_layout',
     'value' => array ('Standard'),
     'not_empty' => true,
 ),
"description" => __( "Select your desired Image position", "js_composer" )
```

Its working fine when even I select any value inside `service_layout` param, but I want it to show up only once there is `'Standard'` Value inside service_layout param ... any one guide me how to achieve that please ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'dependency' => array(
     'element' => 'service_layout',
     'value' =>'Standard',
 ),
"description" => __( "Select your desired Image position", "js_composer" )
```

Would you please check it with above code ?

Comment: its really My pleasure :)

Comment: Bro, Would You please Approve answer so it will be helpful for others as well ?

Comment: I want to create a element which is dependent on two values how is it possible?

I am trying with this 

'dependency' => array(
                            'element'  => array('image_visibility','layout'),
                            'value'  =>  array('show','standard_carousel'),
                        ),